# Is there a better alternative to Visual Studio's compare tool for comparing directories?

Tags: visual-studio, file, directory, compare

I have two nearly identical folders. I need to compare the contents of the files in each folder. Visual Studio's compare tool does a nice jobs of this, but if there is even an extra white space it shows up in the results. I am looking for a compare tool that does the same thing but allows me to do some filtering of the results.

Comment: How do you want to filter it?  What would be considered a DIFF or not?  Do you have some sample data you can [edit] in that explains in greater details as to what you DO what, and what you do NOT want?

Comment: [Take your pick.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools)

Comment: @gravity - example of what i dont want. "1521275       SL.txt" vs "1521275 SL.txt" example of thwat i do want "1521275 SL.txt" vs "AAAAAAA SL1.txt"

Comment: @Hilo - Please hit [edit] and add in sample data, and then your details you provided in the comment.  Please do not add additional information via the comments.

Comment: @gravity - formatting is being removed from the text comments. Which ironically is what I want to filter out. I want only text changes not format changes.

Comment: Seems like this question have to be posted on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @BJ Myers - i have gone over many of those softwares. All of them do file comparisons, some of them do folder comparisons, none that i reviewed compared the contents of all the files in a folder. VS does a nice job of this however it does not allow any filtering of results. So if someone changes the format in one or more files those show up in addition to the code changes made in the files. I would like to filter out the format changes and leave only the code changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org) allows to configure comparison of whitespace characters and have some more options of ignore for common cases. It can compare folders also.

[image: Settings screenshot]

Comment: @Qwerty - thank-you very much! that looks like it is going to work. At the very least it is better than what I have now.